# Why does my script freeze when I press the start button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/SpringLeader/vt56fy85/12/

I'm making a Simon inspired memory game for a school, but my messy, long JavaScript code freezes when I press the start button. I'm not an expert in web programming, I'm still teaching myself.

This is where it starts (when the start button is clicked)

```
document.getElementById("uibtn").onclick = function(){
    var uibtn = e('uibtn');
    uibtn.remove("uibtn");
    removeHeader();
}
```

It removes the start button and hops to the 'removeHeader' function.

```
function removeHeader(){
    var rndhdr = e('rndhdr');
    var rndv1 = rndhdr.childNodes;
    while(rndv1.length >= 1){
        rndv1[0].remove();
    }
    createHeader();
}
```

This part is incomplete and checks for an existing round counter (eg 'Round 1') and deletes it. It then calls createHeader().

```
function createHeader(){
    var rndhdr = e('rndhdr');
    var hdr = document.createElement('h');
    hdr.setAttribute('id', 'hdr');
    hdr.setAttribute('class', 'hc');
    hdr.innerHTML = "<h>Round 1</h>";
    rndhdr.appendChild(hdr);
    Game();
}
```

This function places a fresh round header, 'Round 1'. This will change depending on how many rounds the user completes, but that part hasn't been added yet.

```
function Game(){
    var corct = true;
    while(corct == true){
        var newcol = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        sofar = newcol.toString() + sofar;
        Flashing(sofar);
    }
}
```

This part generates a number 1 to 4 that corresponds to a button (green, red, blue, and yellow respectively) and adds it to an array containing all the numbers generated. It then hops to the Flashing() function.

```
function Flashing(){
    thr = sofar.length;
    while(sofar[thr] > -1){
        var btn = sel(sofar[thr]);
        btn.style.borderColor = "white";
        blinking = true;
        setTimeout(function(){Flash(btn);}, 2000);
        thr--;
    }
    Game();  
}

function Flash(el){
    el.style.borderColor = el.style.backgroundColor;
    blinking = false;
}
```

This function gets the number of strings in the sofar[] array, then calls Flash() that flashes the buttons in the list each for 2 seconds.

I tried tweaking my code a bit whilst rereading it, and now my call stack size is exceeded. I'm at a loss for why this is breaking...

Comment: First, you need a more descriptive title.  Second, we need a little more code.  What does `removeHeader()` do?  Are there any console errors?  Can you set a breakpoint and see where it "freezes"?

Comment: What do you mean "freeze?" In your jsFiddle whenever I press start an error is thrown. Whenever code "freezes" though, you might want to first take a look at any while loops in your code and carefully determine if it's doing what you want it to do. Also when it comes to making a game in html, don't use a while-based game loop as you'll block the main thread and thus the user won't be able to click anything (the browser essentially freezes). Use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead or restructure your program.

Comment: Also this line is somewhat concerning : `while(blinking = true){}`

Comment: I realized a few stupid mistakes in my code and edited my question. One of them being that while statement you mentioned.

Comment: Almost every `while` loop you have is an infinite loop.

Comment: I updated the link to a newer edit based on feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This answer was written before the question was edited. I believe it still addresses the crux of the matter.

When I reconstruct your code into a standalone page and run it, Firefox warns me about the unresponsive script. Killing it shows the line it was terminated on in the console. Looking there, I see

```
while(running == true){
```

There's nothing in that loop (or, indeed, anywhere in your script) that sets `running` to false. Plus,

```
while(blinking = true){}
```

is a guaranteed infinite loop. And up above, you have another infinite loop in

```
while(corct == true){
```

As long as the Javascript engine is running your code, the browser will be unresponsive. Infinite loops don't fly in Web browsers.

<sub>Also, it's hard to read your code. Please, use more vowels.</sub>

Comment: You're generally correct that I have a bunch of broken while loops. After tinkering with this for a while locally, I've got it working like it should. Sorry for the trouble guys.